# How to convert json output to array in jquery

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON output:

```
[{"id":"15","title":"music"},{"id":"103","title":"movie"},{"id":"214","title":"book"}]
```

How can I convert it to an array like in Javascript:

```
items = array(
     15 => 'music',
     103 => 'movie',
     214 => 'book'
          );
```

Comment: do you mean an object?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a destructed object and by building a new object.

```js
var array = [{ id: "15", title: "music" }, { id: "103", title: "movie" }, { id:"214", title: "book" }],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(({ id, title }) => ({ [id]: title })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a):

```
var arr = [{"id":"15","title":"music"},{"id":"103","title":"movie"},{"id":"214","title":"book"}];
var obj = arr.reduce((acc, o) => { acc[o.id] = o.title; return acc; }, {});
console.log(obj);
// prints: {15: "music", 103: "movie", 214: "book"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for an object like this

```js
var x = [{
  "id": "15",
  "title": "music"
}, {
  "id": "103",
  "title": "movie"
}, {
  "id": "214",
  "title": "book"
}];
let temp = {};
x.forEach(function(item) {
  temp[item.id] = item.title
})
console.log(temp)
```